# how to get data grouped by ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have grouped data in a temporary table according to id_card. There are multiple activities for each card. I want to send 1 email for all activities happened on that particular card. But, I don't know how to get data according to ids. should i use cursor for fetching the ids
? Example in the table, want 2 rows for id_card =1 and then 2 rows for id_card = 3 and so on

```
id_card   dat_actitity     type 
1         2022-04-21       tag on           
1         2022-04-23       tag off  
2         2022-04-28       tag on
2         2022-04-20       tag off  
2         2022-04-01       tag on
3         2022-04-27       tag on
```

Can you please help. Thanks very much

Comment: Please show does the expected result looks like and also include your attempt. Also explain the necessary logic required to obtain the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a while loop, something like this

```
declare @id int

-- get the first id (minimum)
select @id = min(id) from #tmp

while @id is not null
begin 
   -- get the rows
   select * from #tmp where id = @id

   -- send mail
   exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail . . .

   -- get next id
   select @id = min(id) from #tmp where id > @id
end
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=061f13dffb8f1ef11b9141a8476fec63)

Comment: Thanks @Squirrel but its giving this error in the select statement inside the loop. The name "id_card" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

Comment: I have no idea what that means. Please show your query

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72052393/edit) and update the query that you used there ?

Comment: Why did you remove the `@` from `declare @id int` ? `@` signify that it is a variable

Comment: because in comment section it was not allowing me to use @ multiple times.

Comment: How are you executing this query ? inside SQL Server Management Studio ?

Comment: yes, in query editor window

Answer (score 1):

```
select @id = min(id_card) from #tmp
while @id is not null
begin 
 drop table if exists  #rows 
   -- get the rows
   select * into #rows from #tmp where id_card = @id
 
   if (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
   begin 
   -- send mail
 SET @Subject = 'Flagged Card activity noticed on Card with ID ' + convert(varchar(10), @id) 
 SET @Message =
                    N'<H3>Details of the activity are as follows:</H3>' +
                    N'<table border="1">' +
                    N'<tr bgcolor=#ADD6FF>' +                   
                    N'<th>Activity Date</th>' +
                    N'<th>Activity Day</th>' +
                    N'<th>Time</th>' +                  
                    N'<th>Activity Type</th>' +             
                    N'</tr>' +                  
                    CAST(( 
                    SELECT  
                            td = Convert(varchar(10), dat_activity, 103), '',
                            td = FORMAT(dat_activity,'ddd'), '',
                            td = Convert(varchar(8), Convert(time, dat_activity)), '',                                  
                            td = ISNULL(str_activitydesc,'N/A')                     
                            
                            FROM #tmp
                            order by dat_activity desc
                            FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) +
                        N'</table>' 
        PRINT 'Email Sent'
        --Now send the email
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
            @profile_name = 'Profile',
            @recipients = @recipientList,
            @subject = @Subject,
            @body = @Message,
            @body_format = 'HTML',
            @importance = 'High'
  end
   -- get next id
   select @id = min(id_card) from #tmp where id_card > @id
end
```

Comment: please don't post it as another answer. Technically this is not the answer. Should just edit the original question and update it with the query

Comment: ok, I am new to this. so, don't know how it actually works. will keep it in mind for further conversation

Comment: see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=061f13dffb8f1ef11b9141a8476fec63)

Comment: thanks heaps for your help @Squirrel. it is very helpful. can you help me finding a problem in my code where i am sending the email. i am getting the emails according to different card ids but in the body of email , i am receiving all the results what are there in the #tmp table. but i want just the rows related to a particular id.

Comment: show the send mail query

Comment: please see, just updated it. thanks

Comment: i figured out the reason, the values in td are from the column from the temporary table, which has all the data. So, for every id , putting the data in another temporary table will show the desired results to be fetched in the email. But, not sure is it a good idea to use multiple temporary tables?

Comment: you need to add a where clause to that `@Message` query `WHERE id_card = @id`

Comment: `FROM #tmp where id_card = @id order by dat_activity desc`

Comment: @Squirrel yes, thanks very much :) modified that and it's working well now